# How to load XML from URL on XmlDocument()

Tags: c#, xml

I have this code :

```
string m_strFilePath = "http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=12414&hl=it";

XmlDocument myXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
myXmlDocument.LoadXml(m_strFilePath);

foreach (XmlNode RootNode in myXmlDocument.ChildNodes)
{
}
```

but when I try to execute it, I get this error :

**Exception Details: System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.**

Why? Where am I wrong? And how can I fix this problem on C#?

Also tried with :

```
myXmlDocument.Load(m_strFilePath);
```

but I get :

**Exception Details: System.Xml.XmlException: Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 1, position 503.**

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> **NOTE**: You're really better off using [`XDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/xdocument-class-overview) for most XML parsing needs nowadays.

It's telling you that the value of `m_strFilePath` is not valid XML. Try:

```
string m_strFilePath = "http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=12414&hl=it";
XmlDocument myXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
myXmlDocument.Load(m_strFilePath); //Load NOT LoadXml
```

However, this is failing (for unknown reason... seems to be choking on the `à` of `Umidità`). The following works (still trying to figure out what the difference is though):

```
var m_strFilePath = "http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=12414&hl=it";
string xmlStr;
using(var wc = new WebClient())
{
    xmlStr = wc.DownloadString(m_strFilePath);
}
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlStr);
```

Comment: It says Exception Details: System.Xml.XmlException: Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 1, position 503.

Comment: It's got me stumped. Must be something to do with encoding, but can't get to the bottom of it. Anyone?

Comment: This perplexes me, so I opened a question about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497371/xmldocument-load-fails-loadxml-works

Comment: I believe if you URLEncode your string before you submit it, it should eliminate this issue. System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(URL, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

Comment: Can you please see one of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55430357/how-to-get-xml-web-service-response-in-c-sharp) regarding the xml response?

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `Load()` instead of `LoadXML()`. LoadXML tries to parse a string into XML, in this case your URL.

Comment: Can you please see one of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55430357/how-to-get-xml-web-service-response-in-c-sharp) regarding the xml response?