# XmlDocument.Load fails, LoadXml works:

Tags: c#, load, xmldocument, xmlexception

In answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496913/how-to-load-xml-from-url-on-xmldocument/7496968#7496968), I came across a situation that I don't understand. The OP was trying to load XML from the following location: http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=12414&hl=it

The obvious solution is:

```
string m_strFilePath = "http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=12414&hl=it";
XmlDocument myXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
myXmlDocument.Load(m_strFilePath); //Load NOT LoadXml
```

However this fails with

> XmlException : Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 1, position 499.

It seems to be choking on the `à` of `Umidità`.

OTOH, the following works fine:

```
var m_strFilePath = "http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=12414&hl=it";
string xmlStr;
using(var wc = new WebClient())
{
    xmlStr = wc.DownloadString(m_strFilePath);
}
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlStr);
```

I'm baffled by this. Can anyone explain why the former fails, but the latter works fine?

Notably, the xml declaration of the document omits an encoding.

Comment: Is it possible that WebClient htmlencodes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `WebClient` uses the encoding information in the headers of the HTTP response to determine the correct encoding (in this case [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) which is ASCII based, i.e. 8 bits per character)

It looks like `XmlDocument.Load` doesn't use this information and as the encoding is also missing from the xml declaration it has to guess at an encoding and gets it wrong.  Some digging around leads me to believe that it chooses UTF-8.

If we want to get really technical the character it throws up on is "à", which is 0xE0 in the ISO-8859-1 encoding, but this isn't a valid character in `UTF-8` - specifically the binary representation of this character is:

```
11100000
```

If you have a dig around in the [UTF-8 Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) we can see that this indicates a code point (i.e. character) consisting of a total of 3 bytes that take the following format:

```
Byte 1      Byte 2      Byte 3
----------- ----------- -----------
1110xxxx    10xxxxxx    10xxxxxx
```

But if we have a look back at the document the next two characters are ": " which is 0x3A and 0x20 in ISO-8859-1.  This means what we actually end up with is:

```
Byte 1      Byte 2      Byte 3
----------- ----------- -----------
11100000    00111010    00100000
```

Neither the 2nd or 3rd bytes of the sequence have `10` as the two most significant bits (which would indicate a continuation), and so this character makes no sense in UTF-8.

Comment: Looking into the code, it appears that Load instantiates an `XmlTextReader` but does not attempt to set an encoding.

Comment: @spender Yeah I had a look around inside ILSpy but it was tricky to see exactly what was going on - interesting question though, I enjoyed answering this one! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Umidità string as Node innertext must be inside < ! [ CDATA [ Umidità ] ] > this wont give any error in XmlDocument.Load.

Comment: This question is not about how to fix the XML, but why the behaviour is different between the two methods outlined in my question above.

Comment: Actually CDATA tags indicate character data to the parser so that XML constructs (like "<") don't need to escaped, but in this case its an encoding issue - using CDATA tags wouldn't have made any difference here.