# XmlException unhandled

Tags: c#, xml

I want to load an XML file that I make by getting data from my database.
However, if I want to read that data, it says there"s an error on line 1.
Line 1 is strange indeed, because I never asked for "ArrayOfBand". But even when it's there I get all my Bands when i put a break point. It just crashes at the last step. Error  HRESULT: 0xC00CE556

XAML on localhost

```
<ArrayOfBand xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WindowsStoreApp.Models">
  <Band>
    <Description>Noorse DJ</Description>
    <Facebook>Avicii</Facebook>
    <ID>156</ID>
    <Name>Avicii</Name>
    <Picture>..\Images\Avicii.jpg</Picture>
    <Twitter>#Avicii</Twitter>
  </Band>
  <Band>
    <Description>Heavy Metal</Description>
    <Facebook>A7X</Facebook>
    <ID>157</ID>
    <Name>Avenged Sevenfold</Name>
    <Picture>..\Images\A7X.jpg</Picture>
    <Twitter>#A7X</Twitter>
 </Band>
</ArrayOfBand>
```

C# xml reader

```
     string m_strFilePath = "http://localhost:17281/api/Band";
        XmlDocument myXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        myXmlDocument.Load(m_strFilePath); //Load NOT LoadXml

        XmlNodeList elemList = myXmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("Band");

        for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
        {
            XAML station = new XAML() {
                                 ID = elemList[i].Attributes["ID"].InnerText,
                                 Name = elemList[i].Attributes["Name"].InnerText
                               };
            list.Add(station);
        }

        return list;
        }

c# for creating the xml file
```

you can see I'm not asking for an "ArrayOfBand". If i take the file and remove "ArrayOfBand" it works perfectly. Anyone has an idea why it's there?
     public static List GetBands()
            {
                List list = new List();
                DbDataReader reader = Database.GetData("SELECT * FROM Band");

```
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Band b = new Band();
                b.ID = reader["ID"].ToString();
                b.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
                b.Picture = reader["Picture"].ToString();
                b.Description = reader["Description"].ToString();
                b.Twitter = reader["Twitter"].ToString();
                b.Facebook = reader["Facebook"].ToString();
                list.Add(b);
            }

            return list;
        }
```

Comment: What *exactly* is the error?

Comment: Check the inner exception, usually tells you what the *real* problem is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load XML from URL on XmlDocument()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496913/how-to-load-xml-from-url-on-xmldocument)

Comment: Innerexception is null

Comment: the eroor is  HRESULT: 0xC00CE556

Answer (score 0):

Your xml is badly formed. You need to have a closing `</ArrayOfBand>` at the end.

Comment: I have that, it's just not included to save space

Comment: @user2827958 - You're not really saving space I dropping one line from around 20 lines, and it causes confusion.