# XmlDocument.Load finds illegal characters in my file path

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmldocument

I have a file with `xml` in it. The path contains a character "ñ" in it, but the full path was `url` encoded before being saved to the file, so this character is percent encoded along with a number of other characters in the path.

I try to load the file with the following code, and the Exists portion succeeds, but then the `Load()` call fails with a

> System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.

```
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    var xd = new XmlDocument();
    xd.Load(path); 
}
```

I have a bunch of these files with the url encoding being used, but it's only these accented characters that cause problems.

Any ideas?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496913/how-to-load-xml-from-url-on-xmldocument

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load XML from URL on XmlDocument()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496913/how-to-load-xml-from-url-on-xmldocument)

Comment: Can you successfully open the file with [`var stream = File.OpenRead (path)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openread(v=vs.110).aspx) and then load from the stream using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e48zttz7(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Can you show that path in the post? Url-encoding local file path makes no sense and without sample question is very confusing.

Comment: -not a duplicate, as I'm using Load() with a local file system path. not a url and not an xml string. 
-I am trying the file.openread route next, I'm fairly sure it will work
-I'm using query string encoding as I'm working with local files that were copied from actual website urls.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, your problem has to do with encoding.  the `Load` method defaults to UTF-8, which interprets the special characters differently.  One workaround for this, would be to pass `IO.Files.ReadAllText(path)` to the `LoadXml` method of the `XmlDocument`:

```
xd.LoadXml(IO.Files.ReadAllText(path));
```

Comment: I'm going to try this next, feels hacky but I think it will fix this. thanks

Comment: This should be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It could possibly be that your file path is something in the format of: ...\User\Documents.... Try to add an extra '\' at each directory change. For example: ..\\User\\Documents.

Comment: I have thousands of other files in the same path that work fine, so it's definitely just hte accented character causing the issue